# Not Able Play a video through VideoView API

Tags: android

I am trying to play this video `http://110.234.149.86/vedios/sw.mp4` through VideoView.My code is below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
VideoView vv =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://110.234.149.86/vedios/sw.mp4"));
vv.start();
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
vv.requestFocus();
}
```

It says it cannot play the video. Can anyone help me?

Comment: check the codec of the video file first. android doesn't support many formats. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

Comment: for supported formats, see here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: what android version is your app targeting to run?

Comment: @Huang "Sorry,this video is not valid for streaming to this device" this is what the error and my file is .mp4 file the android supported this formate as they says it will play MPEG-2TS media files only and MPEG-2 consists of .mp4 .And my android version is 2.3

Comment: @Huang i am able to play only one video from my server(famous.3gp),and all other shows sorry cannot play this video and sorry the video is not in a correct formate.can you tell me any tool to convert all my vide3os into correct formate.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not an expert in Multimedia, decode, or encode area. What I can say is that even the file extension is ".mp4", it would not be supported by Android. Because one extension could be obtained under several different decode profile. In the document(the 2nd link I posted), it refers to "[H.263](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.263)" and "H.264 AVC", So the extension is not the standard to verify if the file can be played . For the converter, [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/) may be your choice.

Hope it helps much or less.

Comment: I converted the a.3gp file in to streaming a.3gp file of formate HTTP using MP4Box command now i can see my video.